# Unable to instantiate activity component when running android

Tags: android, eclipse

i have this problem when i tried to run my app on my phone

```
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flirck/com.example.flirck.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.flirck.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/com.example.flirck-1/pkg.apk]
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1753)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:999)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3820)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.flirck.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/com.example.flirck-1/pkg.apk]
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:271)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:582)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:542)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1056)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1643)
02-22 23:19:43.967: E/AndroidRuntime(29211):    ... 11 more
```

i actually added the support library and it doesnt work

any ideas?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements android.app.ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Recent Places" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: it's unable to find/load `MainActivity` class. Can you post some code?

Comment: Have you added the `Activity` to your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: @user3345613 Post your AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Activities to AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: This should be a comment on the question.

Comment: There, now it is an answer, and well done, copy pasting what I wrote to a comment...

Comment: i actually have 3 activities , do i need to add those to the maniest.xml?

Comment: @AndersMetnik : **"well done, copy pasting what I wrote to a comment.."** - I was writing my comment at the exact same time you were writing. I think you posted about 2 seconds before I did. Look at my rep - I don't feel the need to copy other people.